# how to munmap memory from CoreGraphics?

Tags: core-graphics, mmap

I have an app that used a lot `CoreGraphics` and by using "`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`" and "`CGContextDrawImage`" and etc Core`G`raphics founctions, these functions call `mmap()` and these use a lot virtual memory.

The problem is when I receive low memory warning, the memory used by `mmap()` in virtual memory will not release automaticly, and I don't have a way to manually release them. The app crash due to the virtual memory pressure, my real RAM usage is very low. How can I manually release the `mmap()` memory created by CoreGraphics? Thx